# Exclude utility does not work in mapped types

Tags: javascript, typescript, mapped-types

I need exclude some literals for a mapped type:

```
type ReformValidator = "required" | "minLength" | "maxLength";

interface FieldsValidator {
    [key: string]: {
        [V in ReformValidator]?: any
    } & {
        [K in Exclude<string, ReformValidator>]?: {
            validator: () => boolean;
            message: string;
        }
    }
}

const validators: FieldsValidator = {
    firstName: {
        required: true
    }
}
```

Expecting no error, but has:

Type '{ **required: true;** }' is not assignable to type '{ **required?: any;** ... } & { [**x: string**]: { ... }; }'.

- Type '{ required: true; }' is not assignable to type '{ ... }; }'.

  - Property 'required' is incompatible with index signature.

    - Type **'boolean'** is not assignable to type '**{ validator: () => boolean; message: string; }**'

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible currently. You can't exclude literals from the string, however the possible workaround would be like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NlMeem). Does this approach work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you don't want to be able to assign `{ validator: () => boolean; message: string; }` to keys within ReformValidator, you have to restrict its type. It cannot be `any`, because `{ validator: () => boolean; message: string; }` satisfies `any`. I'd suggest a more concrete type like `boolean | number`.

Second, replace `&` with `|` and there you go.

```
interface FieldsValidator {
    [key: string]: {
        [V in ReformValidator]?: boolean;
    } | {
        [K: string]: {
            validator: () => boolean;
            message: string;
        }
    }
}
```

You can get rid of `?` in `[K: string]?`, because if the key of `Record` is `string`, then the values are not concrete, so they are not needed.

You can simplify the declaration even more by using built-in types:

```
type FieldsValidator = Record<
  string, 
  Partial<Record<ReformValidator, boolean | number>>
  | Record<string, {
    validator: () => boolean; 
    message: string
  }>
>;
```

Which means:

1. `Record<K, V>` is equivalent to `{ [key: K]: V }`
2. `Partial<K>` makes all keys in `K` optional (with `?`), so `Partial<Record<K, V>>` is equivalent to `{ [key: K]?: V }`